# How do I output phone audio to pc?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, audio, android

How do I output my android 8 phone's audio to my windows 10 pc? sndcpy only works for android 10 and above and usbaudio (https://github.com/rom1v/usbaudio) only works for android 7 and below. 'Bluetooth audio receiver' on the windows store only works for Windows 10 version 2004, and I can't update to that version ([update settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTaCK.png)). I want to output my whatsapp calls audio to my laptop for example. Also, preferably not with aux cable. Does anyone know a way I could do this?

Comment: Why exactly can't you upgrade to the current and supported version of Windows 10?

Comment: I just added an image link in my question now. Would you kindly check that?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to transfer the audio files on andriod phone to windows PC? Not sure if [Syncios Manager or Syncios Data Transfer](https://www.syncios.com/android/transfer-music-from-android-to-computer.html#part3) works for you. You can also refer to [How to Transfer Files From Android to PC: 7 Methods](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/transfer-files-android-pc/)

Comment: No I want my whatsapp calls for example to output audio to the laptop

Comment: Do you mean using your computer as a speaker for your phone, or save audio as a file on the computer?

Comment: using your computer as a speaker for your phone

Answer (score 1):

I do this by connecting an auxiliary cable between my computer and phone and making Windows think the phone is a microphone.

If you have a newer laptop, you can plug an auxiliary cable into the headphone jack on the computer and phone.  Then configure the jack as "Mic in" in the control panel.

If you have an older laptop or desktop, you can simply plug the auxiliary cable into the microphone jack on the computer and the headphone jack on your phone (assuming your phone has one).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a newer laptop, but the aux cable i have has only 3 bands (no mic band).

Comment: Ok, it should still be able to work.  If you go to Control Panel, then Hardware and Sound, do you see Realtek Audio (assuming you have a Realtek driver)?

Comment: Yeah, what do I do from there?

Comment: Perfect!  Click it then double click the black circle on the left column of the window that comes up.  You should see a menu that has checkboxes saying something like "Line in", "Mic in", "Headphones", etc.  Check the box that says "Mic in" and click ok.  NOTE: to use your headphone jack in the future, you will have to follow these steps and change it back to "Headphones".

Comment: Clicking on it takes me to "Realtek HD Audio Manager" in the speakers tab there is one black circle on the right which says "Headset (Speakers)" when hovered over. How do I send you an image in comments?

Comment: For whatever reason, images don't work for me on stack exchange.  Kinda annoying.  Go ahead and double click the black circle and see if that comes up with a menu.

Comment: Nothing happens when I double click on the black circle.

Comment: Here's a screenshot:
https://uctcloud-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/abrkar004_myuct_ac_za/EZXj_wHJy0VDivR4OjlETZQBJGzanjM1EtNKBMITlPsyuA?e=NOCgRc

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  Thanks for the screenshot!  Just to make sure we're on the same page, you double-clicked this circle, right? https://ibb.co/LZKWpSt

Comment: yeah i did.......

Comment: Huh.  That always works for me.  I've been using that trick on many laptops and it normally does the trick.  Sorry, but that's the only way I know how to do it.

Comment: Alright. Thanks tho

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering very late, wanted to do just what you wanted and through trial and error made it work somehow so why not share.

1. Installed the Realtek HD Audio Driver, from https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software
2. After installing and restarting the computer, go to Windows Update and download all the required updates for Audio.
3. Go to Control Panel you'll see a Dell Audio inside Hardware and Sound, then go to Advanced > Jack Information > Click the image > Select Mic IN.
4. Go to Sound Properties > More Sound Properties > Sound Dialog Box will open > Click on Recording Tab > Right Click Jack Mic > Properties > Listen Tab > Check the Listen to this device button.

This made sound come from my Android as well as from the PC.